# Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - Why?

Tags: c, gcc

I have this struct in a file "vector.c":

```
struct Vector
{
int * m_items;
int m_size;
int m_extSize;
int m_numItems;
};
```

On "main.c" I'm trying to check if the value m_items of a certain vector is NULL :

```
if (! vec->m_items)
        printf("not fail\n");
```

I do it after initializing "vec" with values - the vector has 1 value (I checked it).
However, gcc is writing an error for the above line :

```
Error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Why is it?

Comment: You have to define `Vector` on a header file.

Comment: @Nick I defined it in the header file, like this:

typedef struct Vector Vector;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the entire definition of `Vector` to a header file and include it in both vector.c and main.c.

Adding a `typedef struct Vector Vector;` is not enough. That merely tells the compiler that there is a type `Vector` and is defined elsewhere, so, it is incomplete. It lets you declare pointers to it because it doesn't need to know which members it has in order to allocate a pointer. All pointers are the same size.

Comment: @cookya the compiler is being forgiving and assuming it will be defined later; like I said above, it doesn't need a definition to allocate a pointer, but it does need it to dereference it.